# Show that there exists at least one player who wins a trophy

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

In a tennis tournament  play 2017 players, each of them plays with  the others 2016. A game can't be end at equality. If a player X beats the player Y in the direct  game  or beats a player Z who beats Y, this is happening for every Y, then X wins a trophy.

Show that there exists at least one player who wins a trophy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume for contradiction that there is no player X who wins a trophy.Then no matter what X we choose, there is a player Z who beats them.

Remove a random player X from consideration, leaving 2016 players.

Even with this reduced player size, there is still no player who wins a trophy, because if player Y won a trophy in this reduced case, he must also beat player X, as he beats a player Z who beats player X.Thus such a player Y would win a trophy in the full game, a contradiction.

Thus we have reduced the problem to one where there is 2016 players, and we can continue to do this down to the trivial case of 2 players, where there is clearly someone who wins a trophy, a contradiction.

Comment: How does the reduced case argument follow? We don't know that Y beat Z, only that either Y beat Z or there's a W where Y beat W & W beat Z.

To adapt Landau's proof of the king chicken theorem (reference courtesy of @ploosu2): Let $S(X)$ be the set of players X beat, & $s(X)=|S(X)|$. Let X be a player maximising $s(X)$. Suppose X doesn't get a trophy. Then there is some Y where 1) Y beat X, & 2) there is no Z where X beat Z & Z beat Y. Then, by 2), no players in $S(X)$ beat Y. So Y beat all in $S(X)$, as well as beating X, so $s(Y)>s(X)$ contradicting maximality of $s(X)$.

Comment: @RosieF Yeah I see now, I originally interpreted beating as beating in any form, directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 2):

This is [the king chicken theorem](http://works.swarthmore.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1145&context=fac-math-stat) in another form. The existence of a "king chicken" (or a player that gets a trophy, in your terms) is Theorem 1 in the linked paper.